# How to locate the closest link/url to a character in a string? (PHP)

Tags: php, string

I'm searching for a link or url in an html email closest to a search term that I've found in an email.

Right now I'm using `stripos('Haystack','SearchTerm')` to locate the phrase in the string.

I also either want to find if this searchterm is inside a  tag, and if so get the `href="THIS VALUE"`.  If it's not inside `<a></a>`, then I'd like to find the closest `href=""` reference and get that URL.

I just don't know how you find relative nearness of substrings inside a string.

Comment: Post an example string you want to parse and with the desired output. That might make things a bit clearer :-)

Answer (score 0):

Try to look on regular expressions ( preg_replace or preg_match in your case ) - i cannot say more now , because i don't know what "relatice nearness" ?

Answer (score 0):

What you could do, is split the string at the substring position using `explode()` and then get the first occurence of an URL in the resulting substring:

```
$parts = explode("SEPARATOR", $data);
if (count($parts) > 1) {
  $haystack = $parts[1];
  // Use regex here to extract first URL in newly created $haystack
}
```